# Why does gmtime_r call __tz_convert which grabs a global lock?

Tags: c, glibc, libc

I was surprised to see that gmtime_r is calling tz-anything really.  I figure the reason there is a localtime vs gmtime is taht the former does tz conversions whereas the latter need not.  Looks like gmtime calls __tz_convert though, which then goes ahead and grabs a global lock on the tz ( which dont even really need ... right? )
Am I missing something here?
How can I get efficient conversion of epoch -> struct tm in a multithreaded application?

```
(gdb) where
#0  0x00007fffee255eec in __lll_lock_wait_private () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007fffee2007bc in _L_lock_2546 () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007fffee2005f7 in __tz_convert () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x000000000041c63f in DateTimeEx (dt=..., this=0x7fffca551900) at /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/hfalgo_src_hotfix_1.69.1-T6J4HNFQDMYVEKV4MEGVD6UCCPG7KHWQDOSVYBUDROFXZA6YINSA/hfalgo_src/./core/Time.h:81
```

Comment: All system call or library functions ending with `_r` like `gmtime_r()` are **re-entrant** or **MT-safe** function & to make your API MT-safe you should locking synchronization mechanism if you want to share the data globally.

Comment: @Achal I think you missed the point of my question entirely... I dont think gmtime_r needs to access any shared data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

glibc can process timezone database files which contain leap second information, and `gmtime` and `gmtime_r` take these leap seconds into account.  (For example, the Debian `tzdata` package provides such time zone files in the `/usr/share/zoneinfo/right` directory.) This is why the glibc implementation reads the time zone database and performs some locking related to that.

I am not aware of anyone actually using the leap second functionality.  POSIX currently requires that the count since epoch does not take into account any leap seconds, so using data files with leap seconds results in non-conforming behavior of functions such as `gmtime`.

However, I expect that some non-portable software relies on the fact that calling `gmtime` or `gmtime_r` performs an implicit `tzset` call, thereby initializing `tzname` and other global variables.  This is a larger barrier to eliminating locking from the current implementation.  (Someone even posted a bounty for this, but at 100 USD it is totally disproportionate to the effort required to fix this.)

If you need to avoid the lock today, you need to look up the `gmtime` algorithm (*Calendrical Calculations* is an interesting reference for these questions) and implement it yourself.

Comment: thanks that was rather clear.  Any thoughts on the second part of the question, being able to get this computed without the lock?  Im considering just grabbing the computation and moving it to my code

Comment: Yes, reimplementation seems a reasonable way to eliminate the lock. I updated my answer.

Comment: This behavior is non-conforming. `gmtime_r` is not a function whose behavior is specified to depend on `$TZ` or on the environment at all. The lock is a much smaller issue.

Comment: @R.. As I wrote, it's only non-conforming if you use certain time zone files.

Comment: No, it's also non-conforming because it has data races with changes to the environment, which is only permitted for functions specified to depend on the environment.